# how to hide mainframe when we open childframe

Tags: python, wxpython, hide

I am doing GUI using wxpython ,I am new to python,..I did a GUI say Mainframe and it has a button when I click it popup a new frame say child frame.

I wanted to know how to Hide mainframe when childframe is open and how to go back to mainframe from childframe.

Hoping for good advices

thanks in advance

Comment: Please help me to find answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used Pubsub to do this sort of thing. I actually wrote a tutorial on the process here: http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/06/27/wxpython-and-pubsub-a-simple-tutorial/

If you want to terminate the program from the child frame, then you'll want to send a message back to the parent frame telling to to close / destroy itself. You can try passing a reference to the parent frame to the child and close it, but I suspect that will cause an error as it will destroy the parent before the child.

Comment: +1 I usually solve the problem of communicating between two frames by sending a reference of the parent to the child as shown in my answer. I understand however that pubsub is the tool to learn as it is the right way of managing neatly complex systems of childs communicating with a parent.

Answer (score 2):

Use Hide and Show methods.
In this example, parent and child frames replace each other when pressing the button:

```
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwds)
        self.button = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, "Parent")
        self.child = None

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onbutton, self.button)
        self.SetTitle("myframe")

    def onbutton(self, evt):
        if not self.child:             # if the child frame has not been created yet, 
            self.child = Child(self)   # create it, making it a child of this one (self)
        self.child.Show()              # show the child
        self.Hide()                    # hide this one


class Child(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwds):            # note parent outside *args               
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwds)
        self.button = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_ANY, "Child")
        self.parent = parent                              # this is my reference to the
                                                          # hidden parent 
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onbutton, self.button)
        self.SetTitle("child")

    def onbutton(self, evt):
        self.parent.Show()               # show the parent
        self.Hide()                      # hide this one


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp(0)
    frame = MyFrame(None, wx.ID_ANY, "")
    app.SetTopWindow(frame)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: You should vote up and/or select the answer if it answers your original question. That is all. In the future, other posters can produce new answer or edit or modify other answers in this same page.